# Use Votes from Hough Transform to Find the Best Fit Line

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to find the silhouette of the object in an image. After applying Canny edge detection, I am using Hough Transform to find the lines (assuming the object has only straight lines). I use a small threshold on purpose, so I can get many line candidates and choose the best fit. For example:

[image]

Obviously, this is more than enough. Currently, I am using the following code, which preserves the first line detected in every line cluster.

```
n2 = 0
strong_lines = np.zeros([10000,1,2])
for n1 in range(0,len(lines)):
    for rho,theta in lines[n1]:
        if n1 == 0:
            strong_lines[n2] = lines[n1]
            n2 = n2 + 1
        else:
            closeness_rho = np.isclose(rho,strong_lines[0:n2,0,0], atol = 50)
            closeness_theta = np.isclose(theta,strong_lines[0:n2,0,1], atol = np.pi/18)
            closeness = np.all([closeness_rho,closeness_theta], axis=0)
            if not any(closeness):
                strong_lines[n2] = lines[n1]
                n2 = n2 + 1
```

[image]

As you see, the lines preserved are not the best fit lines, because it simply preserves the first line detected and ditch the nearby lines.

What I am thinking is, instead of preserving the first line detected, I would like to **compare the votes from Hough Transform** of every line in this cluster, and **preserve the line with the most votes**.

Sadly, the Hough Transform function in OpenCV does not provide the exact vote of each line. Is there any way to resolve this, or do you have any better insight of this? Thank you very much :)

Comment: Just some ideas, you can try 1) to code it yourself (not so hard to implement), 2) pass different values for the threshold parameter, 3) combine it with something else like a corner detection perhaps

Comment: @api55 Thank you for your suggestions. I think I will have to code it myself then...